# Subsetting a data.frame given some criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I return only the Heights which satisfy an Age criterion in R?

i.e

```
Age Height 
1   0.5
1   0.6
1   0.7
1   0.6
4   2.0
4   2.3
4   2.3
```

I want only the heights which correspond to an Age == 4. Which function in R would allow me to do that?

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is not constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
dat <- data.frame(Age=c(1,1,1,1,4,4,4),Height=c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.6,2.0,2.3,2.3))

dat[dat$Age==4,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, since you used "subset" in your question title, you could use that command. See `?subset` and you'll find that `subset(dat, Age == 4, select = "Height")` works too.

Comment: Although the syntax of Matthews answer is favored in scripts.