# How can I extract value from a data frame in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subsetting a data.frame given some criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050811/subsetting-a-data-frame-given-some-criteria)

I have a data frame that has age and corresponding frequency. It was generated sort of like this:

```
ages <- sample(15:45,size = 100,replace = TRUE)
> df <- data.frame(table(ages))
> head(df)
  ages Freq
1   15    2
2   16    2
3   17    2
4   18    2
5   19    5
6   20    3
```

I want to create a function which pulls out the corresponding frequency value when age is given as an input.

For example if the frequency corresponding to 13 is 2, I should be able to input 13 and get the output as 2.

Comment: What have you tried until now? How does your data look like? Provide example code and a slice of data (which parses in R).

Comment: I edited your question to include reproducible code that other people can use to build solutions. Please always include this level of information in all future questions, otherwise you will likely get poor answers (or none at all).

Answer (score 5):

```
grab.frequency = function(d, age) {
    d$Freq[d$ages == age]   
}
```

For example:

```
d = data.frame(ages=41:50, Freq=21:30)
print(grab.frequency(d, 44))
# 24
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  This could be written a lot of different ways, but the approach is same... the 'base' methods for filtering data frames are crazy useful.

Comment: I am not able to post the data frame as a list. This is my first stackoverflow post, I am struggling

Comment: @SonaBinu: You could post `dput(mydata)` (or whatever your variable is). In any case, does the above solution work for you?

Comment: @Sona Very few experienced `R` users would actually use a function here - because this is such an easy thing to do with R's command prompt style. Rather than cluttering your workspace with a tiny formula, just type `DFName[DFName$age==age, 'frequency']` whenever  you need it.

Comment: I have a set of data from which I created a table using : f<-table(ages1).                               Then I created a data frame using g<-data.frame(f). I want get frequencies corresponding to the values in the data frame. I am very new to R.

Comment: @SonaBinu: Did you try what both me and @SenorO suggested? In your case, specifically `g$Freq[g$ages == 20]`, for example? (Please try it, and explain what your remaining questions or problems are, rather than focusing on how new you are).